# Python 2.6.7 not initialing in windows

Tags: python, setuptools, activepython, pypm

I am trying to get Python to run to use with Blender. I have 64 bit Vista SP2. 2.6.7 Python. When I start python the command prompt tells me this

```
'imprt site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback <most recent call last>:
File "c:\Python26\Scripts\pypm-script.py", line 5, in <module>
Import Error: No module named pkg_resources
```

So, I opened pypm-script.py

```
#!python2.6.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pypm==1.3.4','console_scripts','pypm'
__requires__ = 'pypm==1.3.4'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
sys.exit(
load_entry_point('pypm==1.3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pypm')()
)
```

This is very frustrating, because have no idea how to read code or how to use Python! I     hope this is easily fixable.

Comment: pkg_resources doesn't exist, install if you haven't installed it. If you have, search for it to find the directory.

Answer (score 0):

The file `pypm-script.py` (and `pkg_resources`) come from [ActivePython](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/). You probably must have installed a different Python on top of ActivePython. I can think of two ways to fix this problem:

1. Uninstall Python, remove `C:\Python26` and install [ActivePython 2.6](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) (or 2.7), or
2. Remove `C:\Python26\Scripts\pypm*` and `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pypm*`